# Convert or Create TUser in UserStore From a DbObject in Asp.net mvc 5 Identity "Connot Implicitly convert type"

Tags: c#, generics, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity

I am new to Asp.Net Identity, and working on creating my own UserStore, but cannot get TUser to play. I have EntityFramework6 database first in the back end, and I am getting data from there no problem. My issue is converting the object I get from EF6 to TUser. I'll walk you through what I have.

1) AccountController calls PasswordSignInAsync in signInManager

```
_signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(LoginAuditLog);
```

2) Call FindByNameAsync in my user manager

```
await this.UserManager.FindByNameAsync(LoginAuditLog.UserName);
```

3) then in my UserStore I have

```
  public Task<TUser> FindByNameAsync(string userName)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(_userTable.Login(userName));
    }
```

4) When it gets to _userTable.Login() it make the call to the Db and return the object i want, but getting the object to convert to TUser is my issue.

```
    public TUser Login(string userName)
    {
        TUser y = _unitOfWork.WebPortalUsers.FindByUserName(userName);

        return y;
    }
```

I have tried casting, converting and other stuff from internet searches.  I am getting Connot Implicitly convert type and if I cast or convert I just get the runtime version of this error. 
[Snip of error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osSP4.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method `FindByUserName` returns `WebPortalUser` type of instance while you are implicitly assigning it to `TUser`. You either need to cast it to `TUser` if both types are having parent child relationship like:

```
 TUser y = _unitOfWork.WebPortalUsers.FindByUserName(userName) as TUser;

 return y;
```

or if that's not the case then you will need to create an instance and set the required properties explicitly or use a mapper like AutoMapper but for that the type of the properties in both classes should be same:

```
var user = _unitOfWork.WebPortalUsers.FindByUserName(userName);

TUser y = new TUser();
y.Username = user.Username;
.....
.....
// other properties
```

Hope it gives some idea.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, @Ehsan that does help, and was part of my issue. I knew this had more to do with C# fundamentals then ASP.Net Identity or Entity Framework. I ended up going with your second example, creating a new instance of TUser but I needed to fix the declaration of UserTable and UserStore to let me. My UserTable before looked like

`public class UserTable<TUser> where TUser : IdentityMember`

and I change it to

`public class UserTable<TUser> where TUser : IdentityMember, new()`